# Как сделать чтоб Google кнопка не меняла надпись на себе?

Tags: java, android

Я так понял, что в самом гугл апи зашиты языки, и в зависимости от языка системы подбирается надпись на кнопке

Таким образом надпись `Log In` при условии, что язык системы стоит иврит меняется на такую же только на иврите...

Как это можно отменить и оставить только дефолтное значение на английском?

Comment: Коли в доках нет инфы о том, как изменить текст кнопки на свой, то попробуйте открыть исходники класса и посмотреть там

Comment: А с чего вы вообще взяли, что иврито-язычные пользователи хотят видеть именно Log In?

Comment: я даже не уверен, что Google разрешает такое делать. Возможно, по лицензии использования, запрещено изменять это.

Comment: Наверное можно подсовывать английскую локаль по условию, но это похоже на какой то грязный хак.

Comment: @metalurgus может и не хотят, но по тех заданию нужно сделать так))

Comment: @metalurgus Но у меня когда я открываю другое приложение с логином от фейс, то там на англ написано, а когда открываю свое, то переворачивает на иврит... Может это зависит от версии библиотеки...

Comment: если глупый заказчик так хочет, то у любой *кнопки* есть текст. Его можно изменить, либо через `setText()`, либо через рефлексию. Или же можно принудительно для приложения выставлять локаль.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете нарисовать свою собственную кнопку, написать на неё всё что считаете нужным, и в обработчике вызвать GoogleAPI. Например:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnGoogleLogin:
    Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[]{"com.google"},
                false, null, null, null, null);
        startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.EXTRA.GET_TOKEN);
    break;
    }
  }
```